# how to do the validation for two forms in django

Tags: django, forms, validation

In my django app, I have these models

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    ...
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

I use two forms to get/create a `Course` instance in my `Edit_Lesson` template.In one `choice_form` I use a `ModelChoiceField` to create a `dropdown list` in the template.In the other `course_name_form` I provide a textfield by using CharField where the user can enter a course name.

I need to do the validation for these.If initially there are no courses ie `Course.objects.all()` is an empty list,the drop down list in `choice_form` will not have any items for the user to select from.Then,if user forgets to enter a name in the textfield of `course_name_form`,there wont be any course instance selected/created.When this happens I would like to show the user an error message asking him to input a course name.

I think ,I won't be able to write the validation code in the forms.Should I create a `error_list=[]` in my view and put the error in it and display it?This means ,the validation happens in view.I am not sure if this is the right way

please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the clean() method of your model forms to perform validation that requires knowledge of a broader scope.

In your case, you might do

```
def clean(self):
   if not Course.objects.count() and not self.cleaned_data['course_name']:
       raise ValidationError(u"Some sensible message")
   return self.cleaned_data
```